# Woocommerce update cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have a class and inside it's constructor i have used this hook

```
add_action('wp_loaded',array($this,'custom_calculate_shipping_cost'));
```

Now callback function

```
function custom_calculate_shipping_cost(){ 
    $package=array();
    $package = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

    MP_Form_Handler::get_zone_matching_package($package);   // My class with static function passing package

}
```

now this function

```
public static function get_zone_matching_package( $packages ) {  

    foreach ( $packages as $package_key => $package ) { 

            global $wpdb;
            $country          = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['country'] ) );
            var_dump($country);
            $state            = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['state'] ) );
            $continent        = strtoupper( wc_clean( WC()->countries->get_continent_code_for_country( $country ) ) );
            $postcode         = wc_normalize_postcode( wc_clean( $package['destination']['postcode'] ) );
            $cache_key        = WC_Cache_Helper::get_cache_prefix( 'shipping_zones' ) . 'wc_shipping_zone_' . md5( sprintf( '%s+%s+%s', $country, $state, $postcode ) );
            $matching_zone_id = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'shipping_zones' );
            var_dump($matching_zone_id);
            // die;

            if ( false === $matching_zone_id ) {

                // Work out criteria for our zone search
                $criteria = array();
                $criteria[] = $wpdb->prepare( "( ( location_type = 'country' AND location_code = %s )", $country );
                $criteria[] = $wpdb->prepare( "OR ( location_type = 'state' AND location_code = %s )", $country . ':' . $state );
                $criteria[] = $wpdb->prepare( "OR ( location_type = 'continent' AND location_code = %s )", $continent );
                $criteria[] = "OR ( location_type IS NULL ) )";

                // Postcode range and wildcard matching
                $postcode_locations = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT zone_id, location_code FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations WHERE location_type = 'postcode';" );

                if ( $postcode_locations ) {
                    $zone_ids_with_postcode_rules = array_map( 'absint', wp_list_pluck( $postcode_locations, 'zone_id' ) );
                    $matches                      = wc_postcode_location_matcher( $postcode, $postcode_locations, 'zone_id', 'location_code', $country );
                    $do_not_match                 = array_unique( array_diff( $zone_ids_with_postcode_rules, array_keys( $matches ) ) );

                    if ( ! empty( $do_not_match ) ) {
                        $criteria[] = "AND zones.zone_id NOT IN (" . implode( ',', $do_not_match ) . ")";
                    }
                }

                // Get matching zones
                $m_zone_id = $wpdb->get_var( "
                    SELECT zones.zone_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones as zones
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations as locations ON zones.zone_id = locations.zone_id  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}mpseller_meta as seller_meta on locations.zone_id = seller_meta.zone_id AND location_type != 'postcode'
                    WHERE " . implode( ' ', $criteria ) . "
                    ORDER BY zone_order ASC LIMIT 1
                " ); 
                if (!empty($m_zone_id)) {
                        $matching_zone_id=$m_zone_id;
                    }
                else{
                    $matching_zone_id=null;
                }
                wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $matching_zone_id, 'shipping_zones' );
            }

            return new WC_Shipping_Zone( $matching_zone_id ? $matching_zone_id : 0 );

            }

    }
```

Actually my code is working fine i was updating cart according to different vendors and it is working fine on php case 
but when i am updating selected country this php function not working as expected.
The reason behind this is when i checked using inspect element and checked network console i found that when i changed country as a customer suppose now selected country is a and is changed selected country to b .. In Ajax i am getting a (note i should receive b) and when i changed selected country from b to c then ajax shows selected country to b

The prb is iam getting country value one step back

Do you have any idea to solve out this please help me out

Comment: Hi Amit, welcome to WPSE - unfortunately 3rd party plugins like WooCommerce are off-topic here, hopefully you'll have much better luck on [their support channel](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce)

Comment: Then where do i know about woocommerce plugin doubts